# Differences in MIME type between Firefox and Chrome when uploading CSV

Tags: file, google-chrome, firefox, mime

When I upload a `csv` file on Chrome the MIME type is `text/csv`.

When I upload the same file on Firefox the type is `application/vnd.ms-excel`, this is however also the mime type for `xls` files, which I don't want to accept.

Is this a bug in Firefox or expected behaviour? When using Firefox, how can I distinguish between a `csv` and `xls` file?